# Zend_Navigation rendering submenu with partial

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I've posted an edit to my question. While working on it I noticed the problem is easy to simplify.
I need a custom format of my submenu so i have to use partial. But then the problem occurs.

The below code shows the INCORRECT level (0):

```
            echo $this->navigation()->menu()
                ->setMinDepth(1)
                ->setMaxDepth(1)
                ->setRenderParents(false)
                ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
                ->renderPartial(null, array('partials/menu.phtml', 'default'));
```

The below code shows the CORRECT menu level (1)

```
            echo $this->navigation()->menu()
                ->setMinDepth(1)
                ->setMaxDepth(1)
                ->setRenderParents(false)
                ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
                ->render();
```

Any ideas? Guys please. I would appreciate any help!

**Edit**

My partials/menu.phtml:

```
    foreach ($this->container as $page) 
{
    $active = $page->isActive();
    echo '<div class="item">';
        echo '<a class="'. ($active ? 'active' : '') .'" href="' . $this->baseUrl($page->getHref()) . '">' . $page->getLabel() . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**EDIT 2**

My understanding of Zend_Navigation was, first to prepare container and than put it through partial.

```
            $nav = $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->getContainer();
        echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial($nav, array('/partials/menu.phtml', 'default'));
```

What is the point of setting set{Min/Max}Depth, parentRendering at the container when passing it anywehere is useless?

Comment: What does your partial actually do? All those options for menu helper don't actually get passed to the partial, you just get the Navigation container.

Comment: Partial does all the formatting. I can't use UL tag, need custom html markup. I thought partial was just the step to change the rendering with respect to minDepth, maxDepth, renderParents etc. Any ideas how to combine it? I posted example partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code:

```
<?=$this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial(null, 'shared/menu.phtml')?>
```

you should pass `true` to the method `$page->isActive(true)` so that also functions in depth.

in your partial

```
foreach ($this->container as $page) {
  $active = $page->isActive(true);
  if (count($page->getPages())) {
    foreach ($page->getPages() as $subPage) {
      $active = $subPage->isActive(true);
      echo '<div class="item">';
        echo '<a class="'. ($active ? 'active' : '') .'" href="' . $this->baseUrl($subPage->getHref()) . '">' . $subPage->getLabel() . '</a>';
      echo '</div>';      
    }
  }
}
```

before the second foreach you could add a check if and when to show the submenu.

my 2 cent.

**EDIT**

try this:

```
$partial = array('partials/menu.phtml', 'default');
echo $this->navigation()->menu()
  ->setMinDepth(1)
  ->setMaxDepth(1)
  ->setRenderParents(false)
  ->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
  ->setPartial($partial)
  ->render();
```

Comment: Still don't understand you well. Will you extend the possibilities you mean that would filter the submenu? I have no idea how to do it. 2 days spent on it. Please, have a look at my second edit.

Comment: I used it with my partial and it doesn't work. It shows the zero level, just like setting depths has no influence.

Comment: The above code doesn't work. Below, I give you render() from Zend library. Your code does exactly the same as mine.

    `public function render(Zend_Navigation_Container $container = null)
    {
        if ($partial = $this->getPartial()) {
            return $this->renderPartial($container, $partial);
        } else {
            return $this->renderMenu($container);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Came across this while searching for an answer to the same problem. Having looked through the code for Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu, it doesn't look like any of the view helper options are passed through to the view partial, although I don't see why they couldn't be... (in ZF 1.12 take look a line 736 of Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu, the only thing passed is the container itself, the options array could easily be passed along with it, or the container prefiltered, may be worth filing a feature request with ZF)

These options are purely a way of filtering the Zend_Navigation_Container for rendering with the default `renderMenu` method. As you say, it seems you can accomplish the same thing by first filtering the container and then passing it as the first argument of the `renderPartial` method

Answer (score 0):

**In your main view**

*Find the container of the submenu located in navigation config. Then echo this container using said partial.*

```
$pages = $this->navigation()->findOneBy('label', 'Label of your submenu');
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderPartial($pages,module/partials/menu.phtml');
```

**In the partial (module/partials/menu.phtml)**

*Customise. This example iterates over the top level pages of your chosen container.*

```
foreach ($this->container as $page) {
 echo $this->navigation()->menu()->htmlify($page) . PHP_EOL;
}
```